# Why am I getting a TypeError when calling send_templated_mail() in django-templated-email?

Tags: django, email

When I call send_templated_mail() in this way:

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail

send_templated_mail(
    template_name='welcome',
    from_email='from@email.com',
    recipient_list=['recipient@email.com'],
    context={
        'username':'username1',
        'full_name':'user name',
        'signup_date':'today',
    },
    headers={'My-Custom-Header':'Custom Value'}
)
```

I am getting the following TypeError:

> send_templated_mail() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)

From what I have read there are only 3 required arguments, and they are the first three listed.  Any idea what is causing the TypeError?  Thanks in advance.

Here are the relevant settings.py settings that connect to MailChimp:

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_BACKEND = 'templated_email.backends.mailchimp_sts.TemplateBackend'

MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = 'myAPIkey'

#For the django back-end specifically
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_MAILCHIMP = {
    'welcome':{
      'subject':'Welcome to my website',
      'track_opens':True,
      'track_clicks':False,
      'tags':['my','little','pony'],
    }
}

#Email template repository
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DIR = 'templated_email/'
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_FILE_EXTENSION = 'email'
```

Comment: Tried removing that comma after "'signup_date':'today',"

Comment: Tried this and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: hmm I went through the docs in context after the semicolon there is no there are no quotes around the variable. for example  'username':request.user.username .

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try this setup

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail
send_templated_mail(
        'email',
        'from@yourwebsite.com',
        ['to@person.com'],
        { 'username':username1 }
    )
```

in `settings.py` add

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS = {'email':'welcome',}
```

with that line of code it will automatically look for any templates named 'templated_email/email.txt' or 'templated_email/email.html'

Comment: Frantzdy - This is not working as well.  I have added my relevant settings.py to the original question.  Do you think that may be affecting this?